# how to enable proguard with -assumenosideeffects flag in Android.MK file

Tags: android, android-source, android-build, android-make

I am trying to compile my application with AOSP and which build properly. I have an issue with make use of the proguard  flag.

```
-assumenosideeffects.
```

I am trying to strip out the Log statements in my final build and hence
using the following in my proguard file,

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
public static *** d(...);
public static *** v(...);
}
```

and my Android.mk file entries look like these

```
LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := obfuscation optimization
LOCAL_PROGUARD_FLAG_FILES := proguard.flags
```

I tried with various combinations. I made sure that the optimizations are
enabled.
It works fine if I use to build Android studio.

Is there any way to make this work while compiling with AOSP?

My Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
ifneq ($(TARGET_BUILD_PDK), true)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/res \
frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res \
frameworks/support/design/res
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := Progurdsample
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := android-support-v4
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += android-support-v7-appcompat
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
TARGET_ABI := x86_64
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
LOCAL_USE_AAPT2 := true
LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT := false
LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := custom
LOCAL_JACK_ENABLED := incremental
LOCAL_PROGUARD_FLAG_FILES := proguard.flags
LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := --auto-add-overlay
LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS += --extra-packages    android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.v7.gridlayout
include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently we cant directly use the `assumenosideeffects`

**Explanation:**
Android asop build tree not support `assumenosideeffects` due to the jack build server.Jack uses proguard configuration files to enable shrinking and obfuscation. But some of the options will ignore by the Jack.
Ignored options include the following:

```
-dontoptimize // Jack does not optimize 
-dontpreverify // Jack does not preverify 
-skipnonpubliclibraryclasses 
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses 
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers 
-keepdirectories 
-target 
-forceprocessing 
-printusage 
-whyareyoukeeping 
-optimizations 
-optimizationpasses 
-assumenosideeffects 
-allowaccessmodification 
-mergeinterfacesaggressively 
-overloadaggressively 
-microedition 
-verbose 
-dontnote 
-dontwarn 
-ignorewarnings 
-printconfiguration 
-dump
```

reference : https://source.android.com/setup/build/jack

**But we can do a workaround for the same,**

In the Makefile we can disable the jack build server using 
`ANDROID_COMPILE_WITH_JACK =false`

The complete Android.mk file looks like,

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
ifneq ($(TARGET_BUILD_PDK), true)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/res \
frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res \
frameworks/support/design/res
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := Progurdsample
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := android-support-v4
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += android-support-v7-appcompat
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
TARGET_ABI := x86_64
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
LOCAL_USE_AAPT2 := true
LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT := false
LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := custom
ANDROID_COMPILE_WITH_JACK := false
LOCAL_PROGUARD_FLAG_FILES := proguard.flags
LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := --auto-add-overlay
LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS += --extra-packages    android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.v7.gridlayout
include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
endif
```